# ASP.Net Session State using Redis

Tags: asp.net, session, redis

I am exploring other ways to store session state and found some of the sites using Redis.

The problem is that, the site is already developed and deployed on Production server, henceforth i can't alter the logic in a night.

Is there a way, where we can implement a Custom Session State Provider using Redis and save the Session Keys using the same.

How Redis handles concurrency after the implementation of the same, i.e. as Session keys/values are unique per session, how Redis is going to store the values in memory.

Is there any other Session State Management model, i have read about memcached but redis is being preferred as the best one for Custom Session State implementation.

I have tried using ServiceStack, AngiesList implementation but unable to implement the same.

Is there any implementation related with ASP.Net & Redis, wherein, we can shift the Session State from InProc to Redis.

Looking for favorable replies.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you problem right, your case is same as mine. Please follow steps below

1. Add this to your web.config

[image: Note: if your want to customized Timeout just put Timeout=XX in first tag]

2. Install package via NUGet

> Harbour.RedisSessionStateStore.1.1.0.0\lib\net40\Harbour.RedisSessionStateStore.dll

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [TheCloudlessSky Implementation](https://github.com/TheCloudlessSky/Harbour.RedisSessionStateStore), I find it very useful and straightforward. However, if you put CustomObject (your class) to session you need to make sure that it had marked 'Serializable' ( [c# example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et91as27.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-4) )

Also, if you have AnonymousType [i.e. new {...}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329726/getting-serializationexception-f-anonymoustype2-is-not-marked-as-serializ), you need to make at least a simple class to define its value's type and declare 'Serializable' ( [c# example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et91as27.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-4) ) on it's head too.

Comment: Hi, i have tried that too, forgot to mention the same, actually the Website is already developed & i thought of shifting Session State to Redis, which i am unable to achieve. If it got working, then we will declare all the Sessions Custom Object to Serialization. But i am unable to get it working. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Search word cache in your application, if they are present then you have to use serialization and deserialization. Otherwise you need only configuration in web.config. All session objects will point to new server mentioned in configuration

Answer (score 0):

Redis is the best option for Session state,Even now big companies following Redis Cache.

To implement this, you need to perform very little steps.

1.) Add Reference RedisSessionStateProvider (Use NetGet Package)
2.) Add following lines in your Web.config

```
<providers><add name="RedisSessionStateStoreProvider" type="RedisAspNetProviders.SessionStateStoreProvider, RedisAspNetProviders" dbNumber="2" keyPrefix="MyWebApplication/SessionState/" connectionStringName="RedisConnectionString" />

</providers>
```

```
<outputCache defaultProvider="RedisOutputCacheProvider">  

  <providers>

    <add name="RedisOutputCacheProvider" type="RedisAspNetProviders.OutputCacheProvider, RedisAspNetProviders" connectionString="100.1000.100.258,connectTimeout=10000" />  

  </providers>

</outputCache>
```

Comment: can you provide little more clarification like where do i need to add <add name="RedisSessionStateStoreProvider" code and then under which tag we need to add  <outputCache> .... ?